# TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable. When trying to iterate over string data

Tags: python, string, loops, nlp, iteration

Good day,

My objective is to create a function take in a text `data` which is a string, and convert it to lower case letters. I wish to then apply the function later on passing by passing in data.

However, I keep getting this error outputted when I call/apply the function and try to pass the data in it.

> TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable

I did some further research and I am just curious if the mapping is causing this issue?

Is there any way of accomplishing this to make the function work in the most effective manner.

Here is my code below:

```
def preprocess_text(text):
    """ The function takes a parameter which is a string.
    The function should then return the processed text
    """  
    # Iterating over each case in the data and lower casing the text
    edit_text = ''.join(map(((t.lower().strip()) for t in text), text))

    return edit_text
```

Then to test function to see if it works:

```
# test function by passing in data. 
""" This is when then the error occurs!""" 
text_processed = preprocess_text(data)
```

I would really appreciate the help to know what the issue is and to know the correct way to do this. 
Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your execution of map function seems a bit wrong. According to docs it should be:

```
map(callable, iterable)
```

But instead of callable, you are passing a generator expression:

```
(t.lower().strip()) for t in text)
```

as a result of list comprehension. Map takes function (a callable) as a first argument. So, you may use:

```
def preprocess_text(text):
edit_text = ''.join(map(lambda t: t.lower().strip(), text))
return edit_text
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in your map function, I think you didn't understood how it works properly. It has 2 arguments:

- `function_to_apply`: Receives each element of the iterable and returns a value.`
- `list_of_inputs`: List of your data (your text in the example)

Your first argument is not a function, is just a list, so change it by:

```py
''.join(map(lambda t: t.lower().strip(), text))
```

The parameter t of the annonymous lambda function, corresponds to each piece of text like you would have in `for t in text`. Hope this example clarified how it works!

Comment: thanks! it works! Just curious is there any way to do it without involving map? If so please share. Thanks!  @JosepJoestar

Comment: Perhaps `''.join(x).lower().strip().replace(' ', '')` - without iterating.

Comment: Or `''.join([item.lower().strip() for item in x])` - using list  comprehension.

Comment: You could also not use join neither map, and use the reduce from functools:
`reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + x.lower().strip(), text, '')`

Comment: @needtobe Thanks! but will I be able to pass it in data structure with text data? Or just lists? Because my data is a list.

Comment: @JosepJoestar Don't you think it's a bit an overkill (*Simple is better than complex*), but indeed a clever one.

Comment: @DeepakM Yes, you can pass only a list there - `x` variable. Please specify your `data strucure`.

Comment: @needtobe Ahh I see.. Finally, what if I did not know my data structure and wanted to process the text. What if I just passed in a string what can I do for that?

Comment: Maybe write functions to process each type? First of all check input variable type like: `isinstance(text, str)` and do some string processing. Simililar with lists `isinstance(text, list)` and some list processing.

Comment: Yes true I could do that. Actually, sorry what I meant to ask was what if I want to iterate while counting over each text in the string data. Using a counter. Can that be done similarly to the solution above? @needtobe

Comment: "Using a Counter" - do you mean `collections.Counter`?

Comment: yes , was trying to do something like this : `(x.lower() for x in text[counter+=1])` in a one liner without using collections in this case. @needtobe

Comment: @DeepakM I don't thing this is necessary. If you need an index of current iterated object, you may look for `enumerate` function.